# Remove or localize default service dialogs' message

Tags: c#, mvvm, service, localization, catel

I'm using [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files) to localize my WPF project.

I'm also using Catel as my MVVM framework. Catel comes with some services to display dialogs; the problem being that I have no idea how to localize them.

---

To start with something, I'd like to **remove the "Please wait" message from the PleaseWaitWindow** displayed by IPleaseWaitService. How can it be achieved? You can display the dialog with

```
pleaseWaitService.Show(() => doStuff(), "status")
```

but **if you put a null or empty string instead of "status", it will just show the default "Please wait" message** (that's apparently an intended behavior).

If that can't be achieved, **what way do I have to translate the message?** I poked around ILanguageService but I didn't manage to do anything potent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Use [Catel localization](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Multilingual)
2. Register your own types in the service locator

Note that the PleaseWaitService is a tricky one (because it is running in a separate thread, etc). What we do in most projects we work on is replace it by this one:

https://github.com/Orcomp/Orchestra/blob/develop/src%2FOrchestra.Core%2FOrchestra.Core%2FServices%2FPleaseWaitService.cs

Comment: Catel Localization seems like the exact same thing as what I'm using. I assume the problem is indeed the separate thread, so I'm gonna check your second implementation soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used Catel 4.4.0 and in this version I can set message in `pleaseWaitService.Show()`

For example:

```
iPleaseWait.Show("message");
// do some stuff
iPleaseWait.Hide();
```

"message" you can replace with variable who get string from resources.